# How to write this tsql datetime code more concisely and or elegantly

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I need to get the tsql datetime of the first day of the current month to use in a query.

I have come up with

```
declare @StartDate datetime
set  @StartDate =  cast( MONTH( getdate()) as char(2))+ '/1/' 
       +  cast( Year( getdate()) as char(4))
select @StartDate
```

But was wondering about a better way to do this.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0) AS FirstOfMonth
```

Comment: Beaten by 15 seconds :). I will let my stand just to show that this **is** how you do it. +1

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I guess I got lucky beating you to it. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```